# Is there a way to access protected class members from different runtime package without reflection?

Tags: java, logging, reflection, runtime, access-modifiers

I'm making a JCL logging bridge that operates over several (let's say two) logging implementations (like log4j). Depending on configuration of all these implementations the bridge than makes custom global decision whether to log and than logs to all or none of the underlying implementations.

Logging implementations usually have methods like this:

- public `isLevelEnabled()` to test "loggability"
- public `logLevel(msg)` which use the test methods and eventually logs messages via ->
- protected `logInternal(lvl, msg)` which logs without additional tests

Now since I make custom decision if level is enabled, I cannot use the public log methods that make the standard decision and I need to use the protected method directly.

I know, that I can access the protected members from the same package so I added an "intruder" class with the same package as the logger class of target implementation:

```java
package com.log.lib;

//logging library logger in dependency jar
public class Logger {
  protected void logInternal(int lvl, String msg){
    //library logging without additional level testing
  }
}
```

```java
package com.log.lib;

//my class to access protected method of library logger
public class LoggerAccessor {
  public void log(Logger logger, int lvl, String msg) {
    logger.logInternal(lvl, msg);
  }
}
```

This worked fined until I ran the code on an application server which provides one of the logging implementations loaded by different classloader than my application. I got an `IllegalAccessException`. So this is how I learned about **runtime package**s (e.g. [quick explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387520/4222213)).

I can invoke the method via reflection by granting accessibility and I even have an automatic test of runtime package and select between direct invocation and reflection. But the reflection is always used on the application server where the application runs. And since logging is an extensively used activity the reflection is kind of bottleneck here.

**So I ask:** Is there a better (faster) way to invoke the protected method from different runtime package (or to log e.g. via log4j without its decision making)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the access to public by creating you own version of the code, or

you could use a sub-classed Logger instead.

The simplest solution is likely to be to use reflection. I would check your application server doesn't prevent this as well.

Comment: Reflection works but I don't want to use it for performance reasons. I get logger instances e.g. for Log4j via `Logger.getLogger(name)`. How can I use a sub-classed logger?

Comment: @Mrkvozrout If reflection is a performance problem for you I suggest you shouldn't be using logging which is likely to be 1000x more expensive. The alternative is to use a low latency logger like Chronicle Queue which can write a message in a micro-second but thats still 20x longer., but I suspect the 50 nano-seconds it takes to call reflection isn't the problem you think it is.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for suggestions. Yes, reflection is not that slow after all but I still wonder if there is a better, more native, way. Not logging is not an option so why not make it as effective as it possibly can be

Comment: @Mrkvozrout In that case I suggest looking at more efficient way to log. I would start with log4j2 which is almost as fast as Chronicle-Logger.

Comment: That is good suggestion. But still there remains the business requirement to log to mostly two implementations and to control the decision making (`isLevelEnabled`) and Log4j2 follows the structure with protected method too. So let's please focus more on the title of this question or the question at the end.

Comment: @Mrkvozrout if you have a requirement which isn't about low latency, I would just use reflection and move on to something else.

Comment: I'd really like to. But I was told to look for another way. And I am even interested in the answer in theory :)